# Rake task to import sql database on localhost database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I try to import some data to my localhost project and i dont know what to do. My task for this look like this right now:

```
desc "imports the devel databse dump file to www2_sw"
task :dumpimport => :environment do
  puts "Loading www2_sw_development_dump.sql. Enter mysql root password. Just press Enter for none"

  `sqlite3 development.sqlite3 < db/sql/geo_cities_states.sql`
end
```

But i have error:

```
Error: near line 5: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
Error: near line 22: no such table: cities
Error: near line 573: no such table: cities
Error: near line 904: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
Error: near line 914: no such table: states
```

Problem is that there is such table in my development database. What i do wrong? How can i import my_database.sql to localhost development database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Rake or Ruby on Rails error. Have you tried running that command on the command line?

The problem is that you're trying to import a MYSQL or PostgreSQL dump into SQLite.

I don't think SQLite understands `AUTO_INCREMENT` - I believe it should be `AUTOINCREMENT` ([SQLite AutoInc](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html))

Try changing your DB to PostgreSQL or modify the dump to be SQLite compatible.